# Python counting and comparing a Datetime column with NA's

Tags: python, pandas, append

I am trying to get a count for tickets open at the same time using the submit date and resolved date.
My sample input and output is

```
 df.head()

  SubmitDate_NoTime  ResolvedDate_NoTime 
   1    2021-02-25  2021-03-02      
   2    2021-02-27  2021-03-01   
   3    2021-02-27  NaT             
   4    2021-04-01  NaT 
     
   result = list()
   for row in df.iterrows():
         cur_data = row[1]
         result.append((((df['SubmitDate_NoTime'] <= cur_data['SubmitDate_NoTime']) & ( 
         df['ResolvedDate_NoTime'] >= cur_data['SubmitDate_NoTime'])) 
               | ((df['SubmitDate_NoTime'] <= cur_data['SubmitDate_NoTime']) & 
             (df['ResolvedDate_NoTime'] is pd.NaT)) 
               | ((cur_data['ResolvedDate_NoTime'] is pd.NaT) & 
          (df['SubmitDate_NoTime'] <=cur_data['SubmitDate_NoTime']) & 
       (df['ResolvedDate_NoTime']>= cur_data['SubmitDate_NoTime'])) 
               | ((cur_data['ResolvedDate_NoTime'] is pd.NaT) & 
       (df['ResolvedDate_NoTime'] is pd.NaT))).sum())

     df['Count'] = result

 df.head()

   Submit Date  Resolved Date Count
   1    2021-02-25  2021-03-02   1  
   2    2021-02-27  2021-03-01   2  
   3    2021-02-27  NaT          1 
   4    2021-04-01  NaT          0
```

Where I am running into problems is If the Incident does not have a closed date and is NA the function is not reading it properly. I have it in my data frame as a NaT and the function as follows where cur_data is looking at the single row and comparing it to the entire dataframe.

Those last or statements in the for loop where it says if the row has no resolved date then count it in the sum or if the submit date comes before and is still open or if the submit date comes before and closes after the row submit date.

It does not give me a correct count for this if I apply this function to the dataframe above I get this below, it is not reading the NaT functions properly

I want the function to count the NaT's and give me this output

```
   Submit Date  Resolved Date Count
   1    2021-02-25  2021-03-02   1  # this is correct the function is should only be looking at tickets with submit dates less than itself
   2    2021-02-27  2021-03-01   3 # i want 3  here for it to count itself the one above and the the one below since it was opened on the same date 
   3    2021-02-27  NaT          3 # this should be counting itself and the two above since they were both resolved after 2/27/2021
   4    2021-04-01  NaT          2 # this should be counting itself and the one above since it does not have a resolve date
```

The function I am using to count can be explained by pieces:

- (df['SubmitDate_NoTime'] <= cur_data['SubmitDate_NoTime']) &
  (df['ResolvedDate_NoTime'] >= cur_data['SubmitDate_NoTime'])
  The row you are looking at must have a submit date greater than all the other rows submit date AND the other rows must have a resolved date after the rows submit date
  OR
- (df['SubmitDate_NoTime'] <= cur_data['SubmitDate_NoTime']) &
  (df['ResolvedDate_NoTime'] is pd.NaT))
  The row submit date must have a greater submit date than all the other rows AND the other rows dont have a resolved date yet (NaT)
  OR
- ((cur_data['ResolvedDate_NoTime'] is pd.NaT) &
  (df['SubmitDate_NoTime'] <=cur_data['SubmitDate_NoTime']) &
  (df['ResolvedDate_NoTime']>= cur_data['SubmitDate_NoTime']))
  The current row you are looking at has no resolve date and the other rows have a submit date less than the current row's submit date AND the other rows resolved date is greater than the current rows submit date
  OR
- ((cur_data['ResolvedDate_NoTime'] is pd.NaT) &
  (df['ResolvedDate_NoTime'] is pd.NaT)))
  The current row you are looking at has no resolve date and the other rows also have no resolve date

If it the rows you are looking meet one of these conditions then count it as a sum for the current row and continue through the entire dataframe for a Count

Comment: hi! I editted it to explain more

Comment: Can you please explain the question in the form - sample input, sample output and the logic for the output. This problem can most probably be solved without using iterrows()

Comment: @Uts I changed it to sample input output and logic!

Answer (score 0):

Using `is pd.NaT` on a Pandas series will always return `False`. It will return `True` only when used with actual values of NaT type. To check for NaT values in a column, you can use boolean indexing such as follows:

```
result = list()
for row in df.iterrows():
    cur_data = row[1]
    result.append(df[(df['Submit Date'] <= cur_data['Submit Date'])
                  & ((df['Resolved Date'] >= cur_data['Submit Date'])
                  | df['Resolved Date'].isnull())].shape[0])

df['Count'] = result
```

Comment: I get the error ' AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'isnull' '

Comment: `pandas.DataFrame.isnull` returns a boolean object indicating if the values are missing for a pandas series or DataFrame. It can not be used with timestamp objects (single cells in the table). For timestamp objects you should use `is pd.NaT` instead.
The code above uses boolean indexing to find the count based on your criteria. Can you post the code used that output this error?

Comment: It didn't give me an error but it didn't count them as tickets open when it should of, there is an example of the output it gave me vs the output i wanted up above

Comment: Here is a [link to a Jupyter Notebook](https://deepnote.com/project/Untitled-Python-Project-sium0WQ9SkS_8zAI0c3sMw/%2Fnotebook.ipynb) with the code, it is outputting the same results as described in the question.

Comment: OH my god, THANK YOU this worked! Once I was able to look through and understand!!